# Config file ruined my website

Tags: php, xss, config

I am a web developer that have worked with a website over 3 weeks now and I'm stuck with the same problem. When I logged in and was redirected to the `index.php` the session was completely deleted and restarted. So all the login variables and the proof that you have logged in didn't go to other sites.

When I looked in my code I had wrote an advance anti-hacking config file and THAT config file was too good. It stopped hacking TOO well so it thought that I was a hacker (I don't know yet why). And I have searched so many hours to find why it thought I was a hacker but with no result.

Q: can somebody explain why it make a new session after redirecting to home page, here's my code:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', true);
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', true);   //Cookies are a very good hacking method*/
session_start();

$_SESSION['time-bomb'] = time();    //You can't be logged in forever

if(!isset($_SESSION['regid'])){
    session_regenerate_id();    //Now the client can't change name
    $_SESSION['regid'] = true;
}

if (isset($_SESSION['last_ipofyours'])) {

    if ($_SESSION['last_ipofyours'] !== $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
    // The first one is always the right one
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        die("This IP will probebly be checked, we have seen some hacking activity on this IP.");
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['last_ipofyours'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

if($_SESSION['time-bomb'] > time() + 300) { //You can't be logged in forever
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    die("Session expired, please relogin. Or you are hacking then this will be loged and prevented by baning your IP!"); 
}
```

Comment: and you don't see any messages? like session expired, hacker activity or so? because i think `if($_SESSION['time-bomb'] > time() + 300){  //You can't be logged in forever` is always false

Comment: very sad to be hacked. :(

Comment: [Suspicious hacking activity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8qgehH3kEQ)

Comment: How can I report comment, like @Steini!!!! And @RaphaelMüller, No I didnt get any message please it was ME that wrote it...

Comment: No messages seems like it would be a good thing. What makes you think it's broken?

Comment: I think _@AlexanderZhovtobryuh_ found your problem. See his answer below. Unless you have SSL installed and configured on your server, you can't use the `session.cookie_secure = true` value...

Comment: You can be mad at Steini if you want to, but your question does contain some silly statements. "I wrote an advanced anti-hacking config file" --- hahah, what?! "It works too good... I don't why" -- that's silly. You wrote code and don't know what it does, how is it "advanced"? You say it works "too good", but it appears that it does not work at all. I know you're going to take it personally, but instead, you should take a deep breath and go back to the basics. It isn't personal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Secure cookie will be available on https pages.

I suppose you use `http://www.example.com/index.php`
Try `https://www.example.com/index.php`

Comment: Ah, good point, thought it's not quite as easy as adding an `s` on the end. The OP needs to have SSL configured on his/her server. Good catch though...

Comment: Thanks man/woman! This is a real andswer and not like @Steini